# Testing bunch of payloads with WSO2 API Manager using postman

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

I'm trying to process a bunch of payloads (requests) with API Manager testing in postman am getting only one response payload and other payloads am getting fault message like,**"Currently Address endpoint : [ Name : **********API--v1.0.0_APIproductionEndpoint State : SUSPENDED ]"**.

I am struck with this issue could you please how one of them look give me the answer and I need a way to test the bunch of payloads at a time without timeout exception and Address endpoint suspend error.

Answer (score 0):

The backend endpoints are suspended when they can't be reached for some reason. You should look at the log to see what the exact reason is. You need to look for the error logs printed before suspension logs.

And if you want to disable suspension at all, you can follow this doc.

https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Prevent+API+Suspension

Comment: I've already went through that, but I'm expecting something different which would make changes to the performance tuning say like thread.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not following.